# Is $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ for any function $f(x), g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ for any function $f(x), g(x)$?, assuming the argument $x$ is in both of their domains.

Is this just true by definition or is there some formal proof/property that results in this relationship?

Comment: It is true by definition.

Comment: It defines pointwise addition of functions. This allows you to view spaces of functions as vector spaces (so that you can have bases, norms, topologies etc)

Comment: How is $f+g$ defined?  $f+g$ doesn't mean anything if it's not defined.  And the only definition I know is $(f+g)(x)  = f(x) + g(x)$ by definition.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a definition of sum of two functions in a space of functions. Namely, if you take the set $A$ of functions from a set $X$ to a set $(Y,+)$ (a set with the operation $+$, e.g. $Y=\mathbb{R}$) then  you can define the sum of two elements $f,g \in A$ by $(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)$, for all $x \in X$. Note that $f+g$ is a function because $f$ and $g$ are: since for all $x \in X$ the values $f(x),g(x)$ are uniquely determined ($f,g$ are functions) then $(f+g)(x)$ is unique as well.